# Parse String into namedtuple object

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to read back string, into namedtuple?

```
import collections
from typing import Sequence, Iterator
import ast

Range = collections.namedtuple("Range", ["key", "min", "max", "in_range" ])
```

**Ranges to string**

Test object to string:

```
r1 = tools.Range(key='T1',min=-0.01,max=0.19, in_range=True)
r2 = tools.Range(key='T2',min=2,max=10, in_range=False)
r3 = tools.Range(key='T3',min=225000,max=1583515.5, in_range=True)
rs = [r1, r2, r3]
rstr = str(rs)
print(rstr) 
# output:
# [Range(key='T1', min=-0.01, max=0.19, in_range=True), Range(key='T2', min=2, max=10, in_range=False), Range(key='T3', min=225000, max=1583515.5, in_range=True)]
```

How to read same or similar string now into object (list of Range)?

**Parse back String to Ranges**

What I've tried with most hope of success:

```
source_string = "[Range(key='T1', min=-0.01, max=0.19, in_range=True), Range(key='T2', min=2, max=10, in_range=False), Range(key='T3', min=225000, max=1583515.5, in_range=True)]"
source = ast.literal_eval(source_string)
ranges = tools.Range(key=source["key"],min=float(source["min"]), max=float(source["max"]), in_range=bool(source["in_range"]))
```

I did also variants, with no success. I am open to change the string syntax to get the ranges object generate.

Comment: Are you trying to save these to a file somewhere? There are serialization libraries that will do that for you without resorting to straight-up `eval`.

Comment: Could you post what errors or results you are getting with the provided code? This would help to better understand the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ast.literal_eval` function can only parse the following types:

- strings
- bytes
- numbers
- tuples
- lists
- dicts
- sets
- booleans
- None and Ellipsis

This also means that it can only parse a tuple, list, dict, or set containing these specific types. It cannot parse a list of `namedtuple` objects. So you will have to either:

1. Create your own method that parses a string of the format `"Range(key= ...(etc.)"`, OR
2. Remove the attribute names/keywords from your string, leaving simply a tuple for each element. You can then use python's built-in `map` function in combination with the `namedtuple._make` method to parse the list of tuples:

```py
source_string = "[('T1', -0.01, 0.19, True), ('T2', 2, 10, False), ('T3', 225000, 1583515.5, True)]"
source = ast.literal_eval(source_string)
ranges = list(map(Range._make, source))
```

If you really need `Range(...)` and/or `key=..., min=...` to be a part of the string, you could potentially pre-process the string using regex.

Comment: Amazing explanation with all details to follow. +1 for the list of types to understand `ast.literal_eval`.